Why does Aemond focus on a coin in his room in "House of the Dragon" S02E02?
In the House of the Dragon series (Season 2, Episode 2), why does Aemond pay attention to a coin in his room on the day his brother's son was killed? What was the reason for this focus? What had happened?

Aemond is investigating the crime scene, and he is looking for any evidence that can identify the killers and, more importantly, who ordered this killing.
He does not simply find a coin; he also manages to find a secret passageway from where the ratcatcher and Blood sneak in.
With both clues, Aemond makes a deduction in his head: it is Daemon who pays and sends the assassins to kill him (Aemond) instead of the young boy.

Another important point. Those coins had been left in place on the map that was sitting on the table. Aemond noticed that the coins were missing, then saw one coin on the floor, and deduced that someone had passed through the room. Of course we saw what happened earlier: Blood swept the coins up for a little bonus.
